# Unable to load a class defined in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, weblogic

I have been scratching my head for a long time for this error i am getting ::

```
Unable to deploy EJB: 
/the path/FCJGeneralEJB.jar from FCJGeneralEJB.jar:

[EJB:015025]Unable to load a class specified in your ejb-jar.xml: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'path.ejb.FCJEJBBean'.
```

Usually this happens during version conflicts i guess, but versions of weblogic , jdk and everything is proper as far as i can see .

If anyone else has solved this issue , then please help me resolve it .
Weblogic version is 11g , and jdk is 1.7

Thanks

Comment: What weblogic version and what java version?

Comment: updated in the question

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the following guide: [Using Weblogic wiht JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14142/jdk7.htm#WLSIG262) Also check the following compatibility guide: [Compatibility Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e14529/compatibility.htm#INRMP112)

Comment: So, this is a version problem only right.. actually my company wants me to deploy the ear file in a weblogic server(not in my system) and its giving error . If this comes only during version problems , then i can tell them bang on that check your weblogic server properly first :)

Comment: If you not using Java 7 specific features then try to set the source level to 5 compile and see if that works.

Comment: I had this issue and it was indeed Weblogic running on Java 1.6 and my Ant build/environment is using Java 1.7 to create my MDB class. I amended my environment to look at Java 1.6, recompiled and my ear file has deployed correctly.